# AttributeError: 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'bullet_width'

Tags: python, pygame

please help me solve the error.
I have already double-checked everything and nothing works, the same traceback
Here is the full Traceback:

```py
File "E:\Python\Alien_Invasion\alien_invasion.py", line 29, in <module>
run_game()
File "E:\Python\Alien_Invasion\alien_invasion.py", line 23, in run_game
gf.check_events(ai_settings, ship, screen, bullets)
File "E:\Python\Alien_Invasion\game_functions.py", line 29, in check_events
check_keydown_events(event, ship, ai_settings, screen, bullets)
File "E:\Python\Alien_Invasion\game_functions.py", line 13, in check_keydown_events
new_bullet = Bullet(ai_settings, screen, ship)
File "E:\Python\Alien_Invasion\bullet.py", line 12, in __init__
self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, ai_settings.bullet_width, ai_settings.bullet_height)
AttributeError: 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'bullet_width'
```

Here is the code for the "bullet.py" file that has the problem:

```
class Bullet(Sprite):
def __init__(self, ai_settings, ship, screen):
    #Создаєм обєкт пулі
    super(Bullet, self).__init__()
    self.screen = screen

    #Создаем пулю в позиции (0,0)
    self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, ai_settings.bullet_width, ai_settings.bullet_height) 
    self.rect.centerx = ship.rect.centerx
    self.rect.top = ship.rect.top

    #Позиция пуле задана дробным числом
    self.y = float(self.rect.y)

    self.color = ai_settings.bullet_color
    self.speed_factor = ai_settings.bullet_speed_factor

def update(self):
    #Перемещает пулю по y
    self.y -= self.speed_factor
    #Обновлює позицію пулі в float 
    self.rect.y = self.y

def draw_bullet(self):
    #Выводит пули на экран
    pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.color, self.rect)
```

This is a class setting with instantiate Bullet object

```
class Settings():
    def __init__(self):
        self.screen_width = 1200
        self.screen_hight = 800
        self.bg_color = (20,228,255)
        self.ship_speed_factor = 1

        #Параметры пуль 
        self.bullet_speed_factor = 1
        self.bullet_width = 3 
        self.bullet_height = 15
        self.bullet_color = 253,251,255
```

This is the main module in which the while loop happens.

```
import sys
import pygame
from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship
import game_functions as gf
from pygame.sprite import Group

def run_game():
    #Ініціалізує pygame, setting і створює екран
    pygame.init()
    ai_settings = Settings()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((ai_settings.screen_width, 
                                      ai_settings.screen_hight)) 
    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")
    #Создаєм корабль
    ship = Ship(screen, ai_settings)

    #Створюєм группу для хранения пуль 
    bullets = Group()

    #Запуск основного циклу гри
    while True:
        gf.check_events(ai_settings, ship, screen, bullets)
        ship.update()
        ship.blitme()
        bullets.update()
        gf.update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)

run_game()
```

This is a module with a functional game program

```
import sys
import pygame
from bullet import Bullet 

def check_keydown_events(event, ship, screen, ai_settings, bullets):
    #Нажатие клавиш
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        ship.moving_right = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        ship.moving_left = True
    elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
        #Создание новой пули и занесение её в группу bullets
        new_bullet = Bullet(ai_settings, screen, ship)
        bullets.add(new_bullet)

def check_keyup_events(event, ship):
    #Отпуск клавиш
    if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        ship.moving_right = False
    elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        ship.moving_left = False

def check_events(ship, ai_settings, screen, bullets):
    #Обработка нажатия клавиш и мышки
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            check_keydown_events(event, ship, ai_settings, screen, bullets)

def update_screen(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):  
    #Обновляет экран, и последнюю картинку
    for bullet in bullets.sprites():
        bullet.draw_bullet()

    screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)
    ship.blitme()
    #Отображает последний экран
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Can you show us where you instantiate a `Bullet` object?

Comment: Added a class with a instantiate a bullet

Comment: @Rabbid76, it doesn't work,  I did as you said, and the same mistake. I decided to rewrite the code, and hope that it'll work.

Comment: @Rabbid76, I'm sorry to trouble you, It was a tabulation problem. I just erased the tabs, manually put in the spaces and it worked.

Comment: @Rabbit76, thank you so much for helping me, and sorry for my stupidity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature of is `check_keydown_events`

> ```py
> def check_keydown_events(event, ship, screen, ai_settings, bullets):
> ```

When calling the function in `check_events` you accidentally swapped the `ship` and `ai_settings` arguments

> ```py
> check_keydown_events(event, ship, ai_settings, screen, bullets)
> ```

The correct call is:

```py
check_keydown_events(event, screen, ship, ai_settings, bullets)
```